# How to Set Up a Server to Route Local and Global Requests to Different Web Servers (Server1 and Server2)

Tags: domain-name-system, routing, ip, domain, windows-server-2019

I have 2 Servers (Server1 & Server2) where is each one should have a web application on its own
and I have a centralized server (for example DNS Server)
The Centralized server receives a URL request
for example
1- Local Request
2- Global Request (Request from outside the network)
if there server receives a Local request it should redirect the request to Server1
if there server receives a Global request it should redirect the request to Server2
**The machines are all running Windows servers**
It's like I want the server to route to different domain names/IPs
how can I accomplish that?